# Clear/stop scrolling inertia in javascript?

Tags: javascript, scroll, vertical-scrolling

I'm currently making a landing page that includes automatic scrolling when the user reaches a certain point on the screen. Everything works properly if the user scrolls slowly through the page, but when a user "swipes" with a trackpad, the inertial scrolling causes the page to continue scrolling past the intended section. Is there a way to "clear" the scrolling data or completely stop all scrolling programmatically?

Comment: Sure, you can detect when the scrolling reaches a certain point... but if there is no real scrolling anyway, then why have a scroll pane at all?  Show your code for what you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onscroll` event on the element like `body` or `html` to check the scroll position and control the behavior there.